# How to create n number of Arrays Dynamically in c#?

Tags: c#, arrays, dynamic-arrays

First I will ask users "How many names you want to enter?".
Once they have entered,I wanted to create that number of arrays.
How to create n number of Arrays Dynamically in c#?

```
Console.WriteLine("How many names you want to Enter?");
int nameCount = Convert.ToInt32(console.Readline());

//I know following code is not possible.But How to make it possible?

for(int i=1;i<=nameCount;i++)
{
  string[] name+i = new string[45];
//what I mean is string[] name1 = new string[45];
  string[] name+i = new string[45];
  string[] name+i = new string[45];
  string[] name+i = new string[45];
  .
  .
  .
}
```

Comment: What about an array of arrays? Would that suit your needs?

Comment: Dynamically?  Use a `List<T>`.  Too much trouble with an array.

Comment: I'm not really sure what you are trying to achieve here, which is probably why you are getting the downvotes. Is this a homework question? Because it reads like it and that could be another reason. There is a tag for homework questions if it is one. Is your problem that you need a single array of users that expands as you add them or something else?

Comment: I think OP is just looking for a `List<string>`, each string instance already can store any number of characters, no other array needed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try `List<string[]>`

```
List<string[]> list=new List<string[]>();
for(int i=1;i<5;i++)
 {
   list.add(new string[45]); 
  }
```

Or

```
 Dictionary<string,string[]> dictionary;
 dictionary=new Dictionary<string,string[]>();
 for(int i=1;i<=5;i++)
  {
   dictionary.add("string" + i,new string[45]);
  }
```

Comment: Note that `List` is recreated each time number of items is over some value, so use [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dw8e0z9z.aspx) constructor, is you can.